# Is $\Bbb P^n_k$ irreducible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> Is $\Bbb P^n_k$ irreducible?

I could show that $\Bbb A^n_k= Spec k[x_1,\ldots, x_n] $ are irreducible, for all $n \ge 0$, field $k$. But it deosn't seem clear to me that irreducibility remains under patching.

Comment: If it were $\mathbb{P}^n=X\cup Y$, what about $\mathbb{A}^n\cap(X\cup Y)$ ?

Comment: You know $\Bbb A^n$ must lie in one of $X$ or $Y$? I don't think anything goes wrong after this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-empty scheme is irreducible if its underlying topological space is irreducible. It's a [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751450/if-there-exists-an-irreducible-open-covering-then-the-space-is-irreducible) that if we have an irreducible open cover of a topological space, then the space is irreducible.

Since $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is covered by copies of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$, and they are irreducible, it follows that $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is too.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a neater proof. Here is my argument nonetheless.

---

Here are two topological observations.

- If $A \rightarrow B_1, A \rightarrow B_2$ are open embeddings, then $B_i \rightarrow B_1 \cup_A B_2$ is an open embedding.
- If $B_1$ and $B_2$ are irreducible, then so is $B_1 \cup_A B_2$.

---

Let me spell out the second point.

*Proof:*
Let $X$  denote the push out. Suppose $X=X_1 \cup X_2$, $X_i$ proper closed subsets. Let us identify the images of $B_1, B_2$ in $X$ by the same sets.

Wlog, $B_1 \subseteq X_1$, and $X_1 \subsetneq X$. Then we have $(X_1 \cap B_2) \cup (B_1^c)$ is a cover of $B_2$ by proper closed sets.

---

Now apply these inductively, using that $\Bbb A^n_k$ is irreducible.